# Does CouchDB have an equivalent to Redis' expire?

Tags: python, redis, couchdb, key-value-store

Does CouchDB have an equivalent to expire like in Redis?

Example for Redis expire:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import redis
redis_server = redis.Redis(host='localhost',port=5477,db=0)
r.set('cat','meow')
r.expire('cat',10)
# do some work and ten seconds later...
r.get('cat') # returns None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### No. CouchDB does not have this.

`Redis` uses a lazy approach and deletes keys when they are inspected even though they may have expired much earlier. Also, as @antirez pointed out Redis will remove a random set of expired keys every second or so to keep the database size under control.

If CouchDB does not natively support this, you could add a tiny layer on top of your objects to do this work. Add an expiry field and when trying to retrieve objects, make sure expiry is in the future. If not, delete the expired objects. Furthermore, since deleted objects must persist (so the delete action can be replicated), you will also need to periodically find deleted documents and [purge them](http://www.couchbase.org/sites/default/files/uploads/all/documentation/couchbase-api-db.html#couchbase-api-db_db-purge_post).

Comment: Not correct: Redis does both, it expires keys continually and also in a lazy way on access.

Comment: @antirez - thanks for the clarification. Reading up more about the [lazy expiration](http://redis.io/topics/expire) algorithm makes a lot of sense. Let me fix my answer.

Comment: you are welcome. That part of the doc is not very clear actually, there are a few more details: To start the algorithm for non-lazy expiration is adaptive, if keys find more expired keys while randomly sampling the dataset it starts to actively expire more keys. The algorithm is designed so that it is guaranteed that you don't end with more than 25% of keys that are already expired in memory, in the worst case (in the average case this is much lower than 25%).
There are a few more details actually, like DELs synthesized to slaves and to the Append Only File on expire... but that's off topic :)

Comment: +1 @Anurag, great response but you didn't give a definite answer to whether CouchDB has the same feature. Please reply with a definite answer backed by a source and I will gladly accept.

Comment: CouchDB keeps deleted documents on disk too! This is necessary to replicate record deletion to other couches. CouchDB neither deletes records (for any reason), nor do "deleted" records permanently disappear, therefore, without extensive client support the answer is NO. Anurag, I took the liberty of clarifying your answer.

Comment: @jhs - thanks for modifying the answer. I will make it slightly more subtle.

Comment: @antirez - That's interesting to know about redis' behavior in expiring keys. Did you pick that up from the source or are you a contributor to Redis?

Comment: @Anurag - antirez is the creator of Redis, so I'm guessing he just got it from his brain. ;)

Comment: @Matt @antirez I should've googled. Pardon my ignorance, and thankyou for the detailed explanation on the inner workings of Redis.

Comment: @Anurag - no problem. To me, at least, it was just amusing. :)

Answer (score 3):

Good question! The simple answer is "no" but another answer is [mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29).

The idiomatic CouchDB approach would be to have `expires_at` timestamps in the records (documents). Next have a view, indexed by expiration timestamp.  Clients would query the view keyed on timestamp, with the timestamp value greater or equal to now. The result will be a list of all valid documents.

This requires clients' clocks to be synchronized. If you have one central, authoritative server (a very common situation), an easy way to synchronize is for clients to ping couch and check its HTTP `Date` header.

Comment: That's interesting considering this type of programming would break down if you don't have consistent timing across couchdb instances.

Comment: Yes, except it's not CouchDB needing sync, it's the clients' clocks. For clustering/replication, CouchDB has its own system. But the **clients** use those timestamps and they must be in sync. CouchDB is a harsh reminder of real life. If you have multiple systems sharing timestamps, you must keep them synchronized.

Comment: Note, there is an easy solution to the common case of just one authoritative CouchDB server. I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is memcache/redis feature. CouchDB is data-persistent db.

Comment: Expiration of data records is orthogonal to in-memory or persistent databases.